# Swift Array of Self-defined Objects Contains: Requires to Insert 'where:'

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

Hi I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to implement a Graph structure. I have defined Node and Edge structs, and now I'm trying to check whether a particular edge exists in the graph or not. The class and related function is like this:

```
class Graph<T: Equatable> {
    private var storedNodes = [Node]()
    private var storedEdges = [Edge]()

    func containsSimpleGraphEdge(targetEdge: Edge) -> Bool {
        let simpleGraphEdges = self.storedEdges.map({edge in (edge.source, edge.dest)})
        let targetSimpleGraphEdge = (targetEdge.source, targetEdge.dest)
        return simpleGraphEdges.contains(targetSimpleGraphEdge)
}
```

But Xcode is complaining that I should insert 'where: ' in the last contains statement. May I know why it's like this? My purpose is just to check whether an edge exists in the graph or not. The mapping to tuples is done because in the Edge implementation there are other properties; here only the source node and the destination node need to be checked.

Comment: What's `targetSimpleEdge`?

Comment: General clarification: Did you mean to pass `targetSimpleGraphEdge` to the `contains` function?

Comment: You should make your `Edge` conform to `Equatable` so you can get rid of all this tuple fluff

Comment: Also, might be worth naming this `UndirectedGraph` or `DirectedGraph` (which can perhaps both be subclasses of an abstract `Graph`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But Xcode is complaining that I should insert `where:` in the last
>   contains statement. May I know why it's like this?*

As pointed out by @Keiwan below, tuples don't conform to `Equatable`, even if Swift's standard lib provides us with equality testing operator `==` for tuples up to 6 members, given that all members themselves conform to `Equatable`; the latter as described in the following Swift Evolution proposal:

- [Se-0015: Tuple comparison operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md)

Hence, your attempted call to [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641180-contains) fails as [this method is not accessible for non-`Equatable` elements](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L477).

You could, however, make use of [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2297359-contains) to explicitly provide a closure telling `contains` how to test equality. Given that your `Node` type conforms to `Equatable`, you'll want to modify the `contains` call in the `return` of your method into:

```
return simpleGraphEdges.contains(where: { $0 == targetSimpleGraphEdge })
    // note also your typo here, 'targetSimpleEdge' should be 'targetSimpleGraphEdge'
```

Or, supplying the predicate as a trailing closure:

```
return simpleGraphEdges.contains { $0 == targetSimpleGraphEdge }
```

Comment: Isn't the actual problem that `simpleGraphEdges` is a list of tuples, which don't conform to `Equatable` and therefore can't be directly passed into the `contains` function?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make `Edge` equatable (such as when it has multiple context-dependant definitions of "equality"), you can just use `contains(where:)`.

```
func contains(simpleGraphEdge e: Edge) -> Bool {
    return self.storedEdges.contains(where: {
        $0.source == e.source && $0.dest == e.dest
    })
}
```